# How can I estimate depth given 2 calibrated cameras?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I have two calibrated cameras with known intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. I also have nearly 30 points and their correspondences in the other image plane.

How can I obtain the depth of **only these points**? Any code or resource will be really helpful.

I'm using Python and OpenCV 3.4 to implement it.

Comment: I wrote an answer on that the other day, maybe you'll find it helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341007/stereo-vision-3d-point-calculation-with-known-intrinsic-and-extrinsic-matrix/52383055#52383055. The tl;dr for you would be https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#triangulatepoints

Comment: shoot rays from camera centers through the image plane in those pixel's coordinates and find where the rays intersect

Comment: @Ash thanks a lot for the links. I'll try the OpenCV functions.